# Read multiple excel files into R

Tags: r, excel

I have about 30 excel files(xlsx files) to read in to R. They all look the same and I am only want to read in 1 columns on the 4 sheet.

At first I had the following code(not the best code...):

```
library("xlsx", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")

u<-read.xlsx("C:/.../myfolder/name1.xlsx",sheetIndex = 4,
startRow = 12,endRow = 61,colIndex =26, header=F)

for(i in 2:length(list.files("C:/.../myfolder"))){
u<-cbind(u,read.xlsx(list.files("C:/Users/.../myfolder")[i],sheetIndex = 4,
startRow = 12,endRow = 61,colIndex =26, header=TRUE))
}
```

When I run this I get the following message:

```
**Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**
```

Sometimes when I run the first file and sometimes when i try to run the loop.

So I looked online and found following:

```
library(plyr)
setwd("C:/Users/.../myfolder")
list.files()
filenames <- list.files(pattern=".xls")
df.list <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.xlsx(file=x, sheetIndex = 4,
          startRow = 12,endRow = 61,colIndex =26, header=F))
```

This give me the error:

```
**Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Called from: .jcheck(silent = FALSE)**
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Try `openxlsx` package instead. I think it's not Java based. Also, you can try `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")` parameter to correspond to available RAM size.

Comment: Using openxlsx worked very well.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at the [**`readxl`**](https://github.com/hadley/readxl) package.

Comment: You can also use the RDCOMClient R package.